# Create destination directory with drush archive-restore?

Tags: 7, drush

I'm using this terminal command to restore an archive created on a remote server locally:

```
drush arr archive.tar.gz default --destination ./newdir --db-url=mysql://user:pass@localhost/db
```

The archive was created with drush archive-dump, and the restore is on a Mac running the MAMP stack.  The archive is in the current working directory when I run drush arr.

In general, this works fine, but for some reason, the new directory (newdir) isn't created. All files are restored into a folder named "1" (which is created). Drush reports "Archive restored to 1"

Is there some way for me to modify the syntax so that newdir is created, and all files are restored there?

Comment: Try `--destination=./newdir`

Comment: @Clive. That's it. Can't believe I didn't notice that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `--destination=./newdir`.  Drush always uses --flag=value; without a value specified, the default is `1`.

Comment: Thanks, Greg. That was my problem. Using --destination=./newdir, everything works beautifully.